# INSERT data into two tables failed because FK violation

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, transactions

I created a stored procedure like below:

```
INSERT DATA INTO TABLE_1 VALUES ('xx', 'yy', 'zz')
SET @id = @@identity

INSERT DATA INTO TABLE_2 VALUES (@id, 'text') -- throws exception
```

I call it from C# code, it wrapped inside an `SqlTransaction`. The problem is, it always throws `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint` in the second INSERT.

I debugged this stored procedure and it shown that the error came from the second insert statement. @id is set correctly.

I already insert data in TABLE_1 and I get the new id. I don't understand why it still throws an exception.

**Update**

Table structure:

```
Table_1
id(int) PK
name_1 varchar(10)
name_2 varchar(10)
name_3 varchar(10)

Table_2
id(int) PK, FK to Table_1.id
text_1 varchar(10)
```

Comment: What foreign keys do you have defined on table_1 and table_2. Will need to know to help you.

Comment: ... and throw the error trace in, too

Comment: Please define your tables' structures too

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestion :

1. Try specifying column name on your `INSERT` statement, so things doesn't get messed up when you re-arrange the column order.
2. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` to retrieve the newly generated identity. You can read about their differences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).